Apply a function to a vector of variables
Let's generate a data frame:
library("dplyr")
library("srvyr")

sexe <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2)
nationalite <- c("FR", "UE", "AUTRE", "FR", "FR")
cs <- c("OUVRIER", "EMPLOYE", "CADRE", "CADRE", "OUVRIER")
haut <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
wght <- c(2, 6, 7, 8, 9)
df <- data.frame(sexe, nationalite, cs, haut, wght)

And then I have this function :
table_prop <- function(var, valeur){
  res <- df %>%
    filter(haut=={{valeur}}) %>%
    as_survey_design(ids=1, weights=wght) %>%
    group_by({{var}}, sexe) %>%
    summarise(p=survey_prop()) %>%
    select(-ends_with("_se")) %>%
    arrange(desc(p)) %>%
    spread(key="sexe", value="p")
}

I would like to apply this function to the following vector of variables :
my_var <- c("nationalite", "cs")

I thought about doing a loop for, but maybe it's possible to use lapply?

Not sure where you're getting the suggestion, but as.data.frame(cbind(..)) is absolutely broken, I have never seen a place where it is "better" in any way. For one, as seen here, it corrupts your data converting numbers to strings. Just don't do that, instead just do data.frame(sexe, nationalite, cs, haut, wght) and you don't need to as.numeric(.) anything that was correct up front. Seriously, though, what tutorial/howto or class is suggesting that? It's just ... wrong.

(1) Please be explicit about non-base packages, as_survey_design is not in base R. (2) tidyr::gather has been superseded for years, I urge all current/future development to change over to pivot_longer, it is far more capable than gather.

@r2evans : I edited my post. My goal was only to give a reproductible example. My question is about applying my function to a vector of variables, not about writing a perfect code.

My first comment is about recommendation, not about perfect code, I'm sorry if it comes across as a personal critique. I'm honestly curious, what (reputable?) tutorial/class/howto is recommending as.data.frame(cbind(..))? One should use cbind(vec1, vec2, vec3) when making matrices, and data.frame(vec1, vec2, vec3) when making frames, auto-conversion between them is too often a bad idea.

No class/tutorial/howto has taught me how to do this, rest assured. I coded this quickly, and it's not a habit to do it like this.

Using eval(parse(.)).
> lapply(c("nationalite", "cs"), \(x) table_prop(eval(parse(text=x)), 1))
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   eval(parse(text = x)) [2]
  `eval(parse(text = x))`   `1`    `2`
  <chr>                   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 AUTRE                   1.00  NA    
2 FR                      0.526  0.474

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Groups:   eval(parse(text = x)) [2]
  `eval(parse(text = x))`   `1`    `2`
  <chr>                   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 CADRE                   1.00  NA    
2 OUVRIER                 0.182  0.818


Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(sexe = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2), nationalite = c("FR", 
"UE", "AUTRE", "FR", "FR"), cs = c("OUVRIER", "EMPLOYE", "CADRE", 
"CADRE", "OUVRIER"), haut = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1), wght = c(2, 6, 
7, 8, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

